# Can a triangle $ABC$ be translated onto another triangle $PQR$ in multiple ways?

Tags: linear-transformations, triangles, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, transformation

For example, if $ABC = (0,1), (2, 3), (4, 7)$ and $PQR = (-1, -1), (1, 1), (3, 5)$, then the only way $ABC$ can be superimposed onto $PQR$ is by a translation $1$ unit left and $2$ units down. This would map $A$ onto $P$, $B$ onto $Q$ and $C$ onto $R$.

We could also rename the points around and have a different mapping. For example, $A$ onto $Q$, $B$ onto $P$, $C$ onto $R$. But is it possible to have two different viable translation-mappings for the same triangle?

More precisely, my question is this:
Given a triangle $ABC$ and another triangle $PQR$ which are translations of one another, what is the maximum number of translation-mappings? (Not a theoretical maximum, which would have to do with counting permutations, but a real achievable maximum).

Comment: The centroid has to map onto the centroid, for which there is a unique translation vector that we can apply, hence the answer is at most 1.

Comment: Very nice answer! Does the answer change if we stop considering them as triangles and only think of them as collections of triplets in the plane?

Comment: The same logic applies. $\quad$ However if you allow for glide-reflection, then it doesn't, and there could be more isometries esp if we have an equilateral triangle.

Comment: "$A$ onto $Q$, $B$ onto $P$, $C$ onto $R$", wouldn't that involve reflection too?

Comment: No, I meant renaming the points $PQR$ as $QPR$. @CalvinLin But the centroid need not map onto the centroid if we only have 3 points (as opposed to a triangle).

Comment: Why not? If you have $ \{ T(A) , T(B) , T(C) \} = \{ P, Q, R\}$, then by the linearity of the translation function, $ T ( (A+B+C)/3 ) = (P+Q+R) / 3$.

Comment: Regardless of the naming, the translation would still map $(0,1)$ onto $(-1,-1)$, $(2,3)$ onto $(1,1)$, and $(4,7)$ onto $(3,5)$.